# Hbase cluster Error:The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, hbase

I have Hadoop cluster configure in 3 Ubuntu MAchines running fine

```
HadoopMaster
HadoopSlave1
HadoopSlave2
```

I need to setup Hbase cluster in those machines

I configured

```
 1)HadoopMaster as namenode,ResourceManager, secondary namenode and HQuorumPeer and HMaster
 2)HadoopSlave1 and HadoopSlave2 as datanode,NodeManager and RegionServer
```

This is my hbase-site.xml same in all 3 machines

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.master</name>
    <value>HadoopMaster:60000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://HadoopMaster:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

This is my regionserver file same in all machines

```
 HadoopSlave1
 HadoopSlave2
```

This is my hbase-env.sh file same in all machines

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/
export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true
```

When i start-hbase.sh every process is running, but when i create table in hbase shell. it throws error like this

```
ERROR: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written 
by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'.   
There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
```

How to solve this.Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of hadoop and hbase you are using?

Comment: Hi Anju, Iam using HBase 1.0.1.1 and Hadoop 2.6.0. Is it compatible?

Comment: Hi, can you check the master log file and paste the error ?